# Touble when using IntelliGuard2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, obfuscation, yguard

I have a trouble with using [IntelliGuard2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10974-intelliguard-2) in IntelliJ Idea IDE 2020.

When I try to export jar by clicking Build/Obfuscate module I get this error.

[image]

If anyone can resolve this, please help.

Comment: @y.bedrov Will you kindly help me resolve this issue?

Comment: It's better to contact plugin vendor.